# Replacing an icon in Xcode 4.2

Tags: image, xcode4.2

I added an icon image (PNG) to my iPhone application project in Xcode 4.2. I deleted the image and had Xcode delete both the file and reference. I then replaced the image with another image (also PNG), but with the same file name ("check.png").

When I run the app in the simulator, the original image keeps showing up, not new new one.

I have deleted the app from the simulator, reset the simulator, and restarted the simulator, but the old image keeps coming back.

How do I replace an image with a new one, using the same name?

Comment: Ok, it has to be asked, are you sure you actually changed the image? I've accidentally dragged the same image back in again thinking I changed it before... :)

Comment: Xcode shows the **new** icon when I click on the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I had to clean the project, then rebuild. Apparently Xcode caches information in an invisible resource that it builds. Updating the icon did not replace the one already in the cache.